# Recursive removal, preserve directories in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, rm

In a Linux command line is it possible to - *without prompting* - recursively remove files (like with `rm -r [path]`), but preserve directories under `[path]`?

**EDIT:**
For the interested, I've used Paul's answer below to build this handy script for use in my Makefiles (replace $(DIRS) with the paths to be cleaned - e.g. bin and build directories):

```
clean:
    @if [ $$(find bin -type f | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; \
    then { \
        echo "The following will be deleted:"; \
        echo "------------------------------"; \
        find $(DIRS) -type f; \
        echo "------------------------------"; \
        read -p "Continue (y/n)? " -n 1 -r CONTINUE; \
        echo; \
    }; \
    else echo "No files to delete."; \
    fi; \
    \
    if [[ $$CONTINUE =~ ^[Yy]$$ ]]; \
    then find $(DIRS) -type f -delete; \
    fi;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `find`:

```
find [path] -type f -delete
```

Run it without delete first to make sure it is targetting the right files.  `type f` means only look for files, not directories.